# How to make a pager with a cover/uncover transition on iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller, transition

I am implementing a PagerViewController and I use the standard "sliding" transition between my elements. All is fine.

I would like a small difference in the transition though. Instead of sliding the next/previous element from right to left (or left to right), I want it to be already in place behind the current one and the swipe would uncover  it progressively based on swipe position.

How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify: if my elements are images, and the current and next ones are the same images, the transition would be "invisible" because they are same images.

Comment: No one see? I can give more info if needed.